# Wordpress - Custom field after post title input

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a custom field what I want to put after the post title input.

How can alter the order or include the custom field before editor?

Here is my code:

```
function info_posts() {
    add_meta_box(
        'intro_post',               // $id
        'Introducción al post',     // $title
        'meta_info',                // $callback
        'post',                     // $page
        'normal',                   // $context
        'high');                    // $priority
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'info_posts');

function meta_info() {
    global $post;  
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'intro_post', true);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="info_post" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  
    echo '<table class="form-table">';           
        echo '<tr>
        <td>
        <strong>Recomendado:</strong><span class="description"> Ingresar hasta 52 palabras / 400 caracteres.</span><br/>
        Total ingresado: '.str_word_count(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'intro_post', true) ).' palabras <span class="description"> (se actualiza al guardar)</span>.<br/><br/>
        <textarea name="intro_post" id="intro_post" cols="95" rows="8">'.$meta.'</textarea><br/><br/>
            <strong>Pequeños tips:</strong> <br/>
                - Cada 25 palabras, añade uno o dos saltos de línea, ingresando el siguiente código: <input onclick="select()" value="<br/><br/>" size="7" style="border-radius:3px;border:1px solid #dcdcdc;background:#eee;color:#444"><br/>
                - El texto será ubicado a la izquierda de la imagen destacada del post, procura detallar lo mejor posible el mismo.
        </td>
            </tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
function guardar_intro($post_id) {   
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['info_post'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }  

    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, "intro_post", true);
    $new = $_POST["intro_post"];

    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, "intro_post", $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, "intro_post", $old);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'guardar_intro');
```

What I like to do.

[image]

Can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find the solution.

Here is: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on/88103#88103

The code:

```
// Move all "advanced" metaboxes above the default editor
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function() {
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
    do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'advanced', $post);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes[get_post_type($post)]['advanced']);
});
```

Thank you anyway.